# "Cannot find type definition file for '@wdio/sync'." when it's present

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

I'm trying to run WDIO test in typescript without using the tsc.
Actually it works as intended but I get this annoying problem in vs code telling me that it "Cannot find type definition file for '@wdio/sync'." 
Error occurs in tsconfig file.
I guess as the amount of code will grow I will get more and more this kind of errors.

So my question is how I can fix this problem and what is causing it. I don't want to bypass (or igone) it in any way but to understand why it says it cannot find @wdio/sync when it exists in my package.json

My ts config

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./*"
            ],
            "src/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ],
            "test/*": [
                "./test/*"
            ]
        },
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "types": [
            "@wdio/sync",
            "mocha",
            "node"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

My `before` in wdio config

```
    before: function (capabilities, specs) {
      require('ts-node').register({ files: true });
    },
```

My dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.11",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.16.16",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.17.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.17.0",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.16.15",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.16.10",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.16.11",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.17.0",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.13.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3",
    "webdriverio": "^5.17.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the `require('ts-node').register({ files: true })` in the before hook, you should put it in the framework-specific options following the instructions at https://v5.webdriver.io/docs/typescript.html, or in a separate conf.js file that requires your typed config file:

```
require("tsconfig-paths/register")
require('ts-node').register({ files: true , logError: true})
module.exports = require("./wdio.local.config")
```